# Windows does not generate report.html for the performance reports

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance-monitor, perfmon

While I was writing up [an answer for another question](https://superuser.com/questions/586792/hard-drive-usage-causing-system-lag/586830#586830)
 I was running the windows `System Diagnostics` and `System Performance` perfmon reports. The data collector sets run fine, however when I go to view the report it brings me to the `Performance Counter` view. When I right click and go to `View` the only options I can click are `Performance Counter` and `Folder`, `Report` is listed but it is greyed out.

[image]

Going to the `Folder` view and comparing it to another computer that does display the report correctly I can see I am missing `rules.log` and `report.html`.

[image]

The computer that is not working correctly is Windows 7 Home Premium. The one that is working is Windows 7 Enterprise. Is it just that Home Premium can't display the report, or is there something wrong with my system?

I have tried deleting the `C:\PerfLog` folder but after generating another report it still does not create the `report.html` file, any other suggestions on what to do to correct this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Most often cause for that is just inability for Performance Monitor to generate it automatically. 
walk around would be opening command prompt and launching following

```
tracerpt *.blg *.etl -report report.html -f html
```

in folder where NTKernel dump and counters data is located

Answer (score 0):

MSDN forums explains:
Right-click on the 'Data Collector Set' you want the report from.  This is typically user defined.
From the menu select 'Data Manager'.
At the bottom of the data manager screen is a checkbox 'Enable data manager and report generation'.  Select this and apply and the next time you run the collector set it will produce a report.